# OOTB Workflows dont migrate from MOSS 2007 to SP2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

I am doing a migration from MOSS 2007 (12.0.0.6670) to SharePoint 2010 (Just SP1 for now) in our Dev Environment using the database attach method. (Moving from Server 2003 32bit, to Server 2008 R2 64bit - From SQL2005 SP3 to SQL2008R2)

After attaching the content DB, I've found that only CUSTOM workflows have migrated over to SP2010 - and not the Out of the box workflows that had already been configured. (The custom workflows were created in SP Designer).

I have gone to the site features, and confirmed that the 2007 workflows feature is activated, and as per my google search results, I've tried disabling, re-enabling, and doing it again in various orders, tried enabling the workflow features using powershell, and one suggestion that was relayed from Microsoft through someone to a forum post, Enable the feature, access the workflows through designer and they magically appear.

I can recreate the workflows, however going and recreating 2-3 workflows on such a huge number of lists would be a ton of effort - and I'm not sure that the workflow history from 2007 would still be linked (ie. clicking the 'Approved' link, in the 'Approval' column shows you who approved it when, if I end up recreating with the same name, will this link still be there, or will the link be gone?)

Is there any way to get these OOTB workflows that were already setup in 2007 to migrate along with the content database to the new SP2010 environment?

Answer (score 1):

The OOTB workflows *should* be [automatically migrated](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/5304b7b9-00e4-4ed5-b012-934fdb1aa457) also. Make sure that you disable the Workflow Auto Cleanup timer job on the new system before migration.

If all else fails, you might want to consider a third-party product - [Metavis Migrator](http://metavistech.com/category/migration-suite) offers to [Migrate OOTB workflows](http://www.metavistech.com/usermanual/index.htm#migrator/5_1_7_workflows_window_m.htm). They do have a test version of the product so it should be enough for the one-time migration.

Answer (score 0):

With no fix, we mitigated...

After migrating from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010 SP1, the approval task that was still pending would not accept the approver's response on the Approve button, or any response that modified the task.

We had to build a replacement workflow using the SharePoint 2010 approval template.

In one library we just dumped the old workflow results column and deleted the old workflow.  Since there were only about 50 items to be approved, we reproduced the results by running the new workflow.

But in another library with about 300 items we decided that we had to keep the old workflow and the old workflow results column, so we created a new workflow with a different name "...(2010)".